# How to check if a socket has been emitted on

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I access the socket of a client that connects like this

```
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  saveSocketSomwhere(socket)
});
```

Later on in my code, how can I check if `socket` has been emitted on ? Does it carry any state of that sort ?

Answer (score 0):

you have the possibility to save the socket in array like this:

```
connections = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);

    // and remove like this
    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket));
        console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);
    });

});
```